# Magento 2 Outdated JS Libraries - Failed. Outdated AngularJS library found Issue

Tags: magento2, security, patches, security-scan-tool

We are using magento ver 2.2.4 and after run magento security scan tool, In generated report we found following error:-

> Outdated JS Libraries - Failed.Outdated AngularJS library found,
>   response body contains unexpected Security Update 'AngularJS
>   v1.2.17-build.178+sha.2406084'

We have to apply the Magento 2.2.7/2.1.16 Security Update for solve above issue but my question is if we look into above security update (https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2.2.7-and-2.1.16-security-update) then there are `PRODSECBUG-2074` patch mentioned but i couldn't found this patch in magento resource download.

Anybody know how to apply `PRODSECBUG-2074` patch in magento store? Thanks

Comment: I have same issue, Please share if you found any solutions

Answer (score 0):

That's because that is an internal refference for Magento, not really a patch name.
You need to download Magento 2.2.7 and get the files from setup/pub/angular and replace your local ones. This shouldn't affect your site as these files are being used during setup wizard.